# JBoss 7.1 - Constant heap increase

Tags: memory, jboss

I've been tasked with analyzing some memory consumption issues with one of our web apps. I'd made myself passibly familiar with tools like Mission Control and VisualVM and used them to resolve a number of leaks, but in doing so came across behavior for which I can't account.

**Setup**

- JBoss 7.1.1 AS
- Java 1.7.0_67

Specifically, I've found that even when I run only JBoss 7 by itself (that is, I turn off the deployer and just let the server itself run) I can see regular allocations (followed by garbage collection) of about 1MB/3 seconds or so.

On a whim, I took heap dumps immediately after doing a GC and then once the allocations had been going on. It seems like the majority of the objects I'm seeing have to do with modules, either Xerces activity (reading the module XML, I guess?) or objects associated with ModuleLoader. The majority of the objects I see all have 'References' that look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlUmv.png (sorry, I can't mark up images)

My thinking (which may be entirely off base) was that JBoss scans for new modules to support hot deploys? The thing is though, that use case isn't one I ever use: new deployments always involve just shutting down the server, so dynamically scanning for modules is really unnecessary.

I guess my questions are:

- Does my belief about module loading have any merit?

  - If so, is there any way to get JBoss to stop scanning?
  - If not, does anyone have any suggestions about what else I can investigate?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you can configure scanning behaviour in `urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner` subsystem in `standalone.xml`.

Comment: Neeraj: thanks for the comment. Like I mentioned, I see this behavior with the deployment scanner turned off (I've even gone so far as to remove the module and its settings from standalone, no change).

Comment: ok, how much memory jboss is taking(maximum). can you share your standalone? I will try it in my jBoss.